# Bridge in unidirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am thinking of easiest way to check if two vertices (edge) is a bridge in unidirected graph G? My graph is represented by adjecency list.

Comment: Define ***easiest*** ?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc easiest to understand :)

Comment: Juan Lopes's answer is the easiest way.  If you need to do this for all possible edges, it will be faster to use an algorithm for biconnected components.

Answer (score 1):

(The easiest to understand isn't necessarily the best way.)

Run DFS and count the number of components. Remove the edge and run the DFS again. If the number of components increased, that was a bridge.